# sqlite3 .executemany: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm running this line:

```
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO frame VALUES (?,?)', list( ((f[0],), tuple(f[1])) )   )
```

This is f: `('Constructed_Restraints', ['hogtie', 'hobble'])`

So this is what the 2nd argument of my .executemany line becomes:

```
[('Constructed_Restraints',), ('hogtie', 'hobble')]
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.
```

I've tried nearly everything in various SO answers to other questions, but I continue getting this error. How am I only providing 1 binding? The list has 2 tuples in it.

Comment: your first tuple contains only 1 value, your query expects 2

Comment: Ok, but when I make my argument a single tuple: ('Overeating', ('scarf', 'obese')), I get the error that there are 10 bindings supplied, because overeating has 10 letters.

Comment: `executemany` will repeat the query with each tuple provided, and will try to unpack 2 values, in your case. Are you sure about `executemany` ? maybe you need `execute` ?

Comment: I had tried .execute earlier, but I got this error: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type. If it helps, my sql table has 2 columns(one with type TEXT, the other with type BLOB). Does my 2nd parameter need to be a list and not a tuple? Thanks!

Comment: in other words `executemany` is used to create multiple rows. so i think you need `execute` but you cannot store a tuple as BLOB directly, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260095/saving-tuples-as-blob-data-types-in-sqlite3-in-python) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want two rows inserted with a null in the second field, try this:

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO frame VALUES (?,?)', list( ((f[0],None), tuple(f[1])) )
```

On the other hand, if you want one row inserted with some sort of serialised value, try:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO frame VALUES (?,?)', (f[0], ','.join(f[1])) )
```

The latter will insert the second value in comma separated value syntax which poses normalisation problems.  Going beyond this probably requires database thinking, but SQLite is pretty capable so the query issues can probably be handled in place (insert and update anomalies on the other hand are different).